# Implement Swift function with completion block outside parameter set

Tags: swift, swift2

As I understood right we can use function

```
func saveImage(imageType:imageType, thumb: UIImage, completion: CompletionHandler)
```

like this:

```
imageSaver.saveImage(someType, thumb:image) { in
...
}
```

but actually as from Objective-C I suppose that block is a parameter and maybe should I use it like this:

```
imageSaver.saveImage(someType, thumb:image, { in
...
})
```

Also one more that is interesting for me as Objective-C coder it's passing arguments to a function:

so if I want to add some params to savaImage function like this:

```
func saveImage(someInt:UInt, imageType:imageType, thumb: UIImage, completion: CompletionHandler)
```

then I should call it with specifying `imageType` name.

```
imageSaver.saveImage(10, imageType:someType, thumb:image) { in
...
}
```

I guess in Swift we have something like skipping definition of function

Objective-C example:

```
- (void)saveImage:(UIImage *)image withParams:(NSDictionary *)params
```

So `withParams` sometimes can be skipped at start of function, as I understood right, which is not quite obvious for me)

Comment: what question are you asking?

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ my question is it legal to implement block outside () of function, so as I see it's a last parameter of function. in objective c we did not use it like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that's part of the purpose of the distinction between a closure and a function. It's not really defining a block outside the function, so much as some syntactic sugar to improve readability.

I would suggest reading through this: [Closure Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)

Comment: ok got it, but it means that it will work only in case if the closure is a last param in the function. right?

Comment: I believe that's correct. It also doesn't work from within "if let" or "guard let" statements